# Formatting (one column in one line) in Toad when generating schema script

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, toad

I am using Toad for Oracle Professional version 9.7.2.5.

I go to 'Database' Menu, select Export -> Generate Schema script.

The result is like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW Schema.V1
(col1,col2,col3)
AS
SELECT col1,col2,col3 
FROM table1
```

I want it to be like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW Schema.V1
(
   col1,
   col2,
   col3
)
AS
   SELECT col1,
          col2,
          col3
   FROM table1
```

i.e., i want the columns to be one per each line. I have a exported file that was generated last year and it is like one column per line (the second one above). Not sure what i should do to get the same formatting.

I am trying to compare last years file and todays file. These formatted columns are shown as differences making it hard to see the actual difference.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: use other utilities to compare the files like `winmerge` http://winmerge.org/
that would help you to ignore white spaces, additional lines, and other formatting problem and can easily match the content.

Answer (score 0):

Go to View>Toad Options and look at Scripts on left side, then see the options on the right side. There are a full range of configuration options there.  By the way, the current Toad for Oracle version is 12.6.  You are back a few versions and missing some important functionalities.